# Defining scope for custom Sublime Text 2 snippets

Tags: scope, sublimetext2, code-snippets

While trying to write my own snippets for Sublime Text 2, I ran into the following two problems:

1. **Finding scope keys**. I figured out that I can look through my packages one by one and find references to a declared "scope" property. For example in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/JavaScript/Comments.tmPreferences` (a file in my HTML package) there's these two lines:

   ```
   <key>scope</key>
   <string>source.js</string>
   ```

   So if I want my current snippet to work on javascript files, I define my scope like:

   ```
   <scope>source.js</scope>
   ```

   I'm assuming all these scope keys are defined on-the-fly based on what Packages I have installed. Does Sublime Text build a list anywhere that I can more easily reference? Perusing through a bunch of package files seems overly tedious.
2. **Defining multiple scope properties**. This I've figured out, and the following line allows my snippet to work in both HTML and JavaScript files.

   ```
   <scope>text.html, source.js</scope>
   ```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### View Current Scope of Cursor Position

1. Place your cursor in the file where you wish to know the scope.
2. Use this keyboard-shortcut:

   **Windows**: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
   **Mac:** <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
3. The current scope will be displayed in the left side of the status bar on Windows, or in a popup window on Mac.

Use these as the `<scope>` key in your `foo.sublime-snippet` file.

The returned scopes are listed generic to specific. Choose the scope(s) which best "scoped" the snippet to where it should be available to tab trigger.

Comment: I don't see such a value in the status bar. Could you provide a screen shot?

Comment: Neither do I. This must be dependent on some package.

Comment: It is package dependent; the package is called *Scope Hunter*, and there's a link in my answer below.

Comment: It's ctrl+shift+p on OS X.

Comment: For those not seeing the value in the status bar, look at the bottom **left**. You should see, for example, source.js

Answer (score 146):

Here is a list of scopes to use in Sublime Text 2 snippets -

```
ActionScript: source.actionscript.2
AppleScript: source.applescript
ASP: source.asp
Batch FIle: source.dosbatch
C#: source.cs
C++: source.c++
Clojure: source.clojure
CoffeeScript: source.coffee
CSS: source.css
D: source.d
Diff: source.diff
Erlang: source.erlang
Go: source.go
GraphViz: source.dot
Groovy: source.groovy
Haskell: source.haskell
HTML: text.html(.basic)
JSP: text.html.jsp
Java: source.java
Java Properties: source.java-props
Java Doc: text.html.javadoc
JSON: source.json
Javascript: source.js
BibTex: source.bibtex
Latex Log: text.log.latex
Latex Memoir: text.tex.latex.memoir
Latex: text.tex.latex
LESS: source.css.less
TeX: text.tex
Lisp: source.lisp
Lua: source.lua
MakeFile: source.makefile
Markdown: text.html.markdown
Multi Markdown: text.html.markdown.multimarkdown
Matlab: source.matlab
Objective-C: source.objc
Objective-C++: source.objc++
OCaml campl4: source.camlp4.ocaml
OCaml: source.ocaml
OCamllex: source.ocamllex
Perl: source.perl
PHP: source.php
Regular Expression(python): source.regexp.python
Python: source.python
R Console: source.r-console
R: source.r
Ruby on Rails: source.ruby.rails
Ruby HAML: text.haml
SQL(Ruby): source.sql.ruby
Regular Expression: source.regexp
RestructuredText: text.restructuredtext
Ruby: source.ruby
SASS: source.sass
Scala: source.scala
Shell Script: source.shell
SQL: source.sql
Stylus: source.stylus
TCL: source.tcl
HTML(TCL): text.html.tcl
Plain text: text.plain
Textile: text.html.textile
XML: text.xml
XSL: text.xml.xsl
YAML: source.yaml
```

If anything is missing, add it in this gist https://gist.github.com/4705378.

Comment: When I click on Tools -> New Snippet, a file opens, I want to display this list on that file. Because I don't go often there but I also don't want to Google again for this.

Comment: Bookmark this page. It's going to be much less work than going through a huge list and then deleting all the other lines.

Comment: You mean to say that there is no such thing as default snippet code file?

Answer (score 8):

There's a package called **Scope Hunter**, by [Isaac Muse](https://github.com/facelessuser), which is really helpful for this.

It can show you the scope under any cursor in a document, which I've found really helpful when debugging my own snippets. Sometimes it's very detailed; a sample scope from my frontmost document:

```
Scope: text.tex.latex
       meta.function.environment.list.latex
       meta.function.environment.general.latex
       meta.function.environment.math.latex
       string.other.math.block.environment.latex
       meta.group.braces.tex
       meta.space-after-command.latex
```

(Wrapped for ease of reading)

I wouldn't have been able to find that if I spent a week picking SL2 apart, but this package gets it in seconds. Highly recommended.

This level of detail also means that you can define snippets in a very granular way, if you want. For example, the `meta.function.environment.list.latex` corresponds broadly to lists in LaTeX, so I have a snippet that inserts a new `\item` when I press super+enter in a list environment, but nobody else. I can target snippets much more effectively than with blind guesswork.

The source code is [in **Github**](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter), or you can install it through **Package Control**.

Comment: I just uninstalled it since I can just get that info with a keystroke (as specified in the accepted answer)

Comment: thanks for the note on the usefulness of highly specific scopes!

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you can use the Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P (without using Scope Hunter) and it will show you the scope on the bottom bar on the left side right after the Col/Line information. It's pretty small print but it's there.

Answer (score 5):

To answer, #1, look in the syntax's *.tmLanguage* file, look for the key: `scopeName`.  This is what the syntax uses for the snippet's scope value.

For example, an excerpt from [nathos / sass-textmate-bundle](https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle/blob/master/Syntaxes/Sass.tmLanguage)

```
<key>scopeName</key>
<string>source.sass</string>
```

So you would use `source.sass` in your snippet.

Here is more info on [defining a syntax](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html)