# How can I define a custom scope for snippets in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: scope, sublimetext2, code-snippets

I have the following snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
{{#_}}${1:$SELECTION}{{/_}}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>i18n</tabTrigger>
    <!-- What can I put in scope? -->
    <scope>text.handlebars</scope>
</snippet>
```

But I only want it to be available within files that end in ".handlebars".  I want to do this because I want to overload the i18n tab trigger for several different filetypes.  Right now, I am stuck with renaming the tab trigger for this particular case.

This question is very useful for existing scopes:  [Defining scope for custom Sublime Text 2 snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922174/defining-scope-for-custom-sublime-text-2-snippets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your handlebars example, [nrw / sublime-text-handlebars](https://github.com/nrw/sublime-text-handlebars) uses `text.html.handlebars`.  You'll need the *Handlebars.tmLanguage* file to have the syntax.

*Edit*: The scope name is defined by the `scopeName` key in the syntax's tmLanguage file.  Again for your example, line 681 of *Handlebars.tmLanguage*:

```
<key>scopeName</key>
<string>text.html.handlebars</string>
```

To create your own syntax definition, see [this unofficial documentation article](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html).  `scopeName` sets the value that should be used for the scope key in the snippet definition.